# Is it possible to start pax-run without the Gogo shell?

Tags: osgi, openshift, apache-felix, pax-runner, gogo-shell

I'm trying to deploy an application which is provisioned with pax-run. However, it seems that it insists on installing the Gogo bundles. Since when the application is executed it does not get a terminal allocated, Gogo closes and stops the application with it.

I have found no way to remove to Gogo bundles or at least prevent them from stopping. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxrunner/Options) of Pax Runner, you can turn off the console with

```
--console=false
```

It's also possible to run as deamon

```
pax-rund --startd
```

Comment: Ugh, somehow I managed to miss the reference that was right in front of me. Thanks!